# Comparing current element's sub-elements/child attributes with the following element's sub-elements/child attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, schematron

I am trying to write schematron rule to compare an attribute of a current sub-element (End @value) in a loop with next sub-elements attribute(Origin @value). I am not sure if i am doing the right thing so here is my attempt

Here is my attempt:

```
<sch:rule context="test">
    <sch:assert test="End/@value = following-sibling::test/Origin/@value " >Both the value are not Equal. </sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

This rule is working fine till the last element, the last element is expecting another element which is not present. the problem could be with "following-sibling" .

Here is XML file:

```
<tests>
<test x="-276.724" xEnd="-276.193">
    <Origin value="36.599"/>
    <End value="36.6"/>
</test>
<test x="-276.193" xEnd="-260.29">
    <Origin value="36.6"/>
    <End value="36.603"/>
</test>
<test x="-260.29" xEnd="-240.194">
    <Origin value="36.603"/>
    <End value="36.601"/>
</test>
<test x="-240.194" xEnd="-220.046">
    <Origin value="36.601"/>
    <End value="36.601"/>
</test>
<test x="-220.046" xEnd="-200.09">
    <Origin value="36.601"/>
    <End value="36.602"/>
</test>
```

Expected result:
As current sub-element (End @value) = next sub-elements attribute(Origin @value), the Output should be success.

Actual result.

```
    <test x="-220.046" xEnd="-200.09">
    <Origin value="36.601"/>
    <End value="36.602"/>
</test>
```

foe this element i am getting assretion failure

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the XSLT 2.0 binding.

If so, `End/@value = following-sibling::test/Origin/@value` is comparing the `value` attribute of the `End` child element with the `value` attribute of the `Origin` child element of **every** following sibling `test` element. That evaluates to true if *any* of the `Origin/@value` values match.  That's probably not what you want.

The `End` and `Origin` elements are both children of the `test` element, which is the context for your XPath expressions.  If you want to test the two child elements:

```
<sch:rule context="test">
  <sch:assert test="End/@value = Origin/@value"
  >Both the  value are not Equal. </sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

If you want to test the `End/@value` from the current `test` element with the `Origin/@value` from the following `test` element but not fail when there is no following `test` element:

```
<sch:rule context="test[exists(following-sibling::test[1])]">
  <sch:assert test="End/@value = following-sibling::test[1]/Origin/@value"
  >Both the  value are not Equal. </sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

The `[1]` limits the XPath to selecting just the first `test`.